# How do I create a JAR where the package is in the root folder? (and not inside a bin folder)

Tags: java, unix, jar, command

I am trying to create a jar from the command line using the following:

`jar cfm EWSTerabot.jar ./MyManifest.txt ./bin/ews/`

However, when I execute the JAR, I get the following error  *"Could not find or load main class ews.main.gateway.Main"*

The reason I receive this error is that when I extract the JAR and look inside, the main class is at bin/ews/main/gateway/Main.class. How do I create the JAR so that the ews folder is at the root and the Main class is located at ews/main/gateway/Main.class. I essentially want to create the JAR without this bin folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the offical jar documentation (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html) :

```
jar cfm EWSTerabot.jar ./MyManifest.txt -C ./bin .
```

use -C to specify a different directory than the current.

Comment: Thanks! I have some external libraries (in the form of jars) I need to import. They are located at ./libs. How can I package these with the JAR?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "package with the jar". If it is acceptable to have them in the same directory as your EWSTerabot.jar you can specify them in the manifest.mf file:
Class-Path: lib/library1.jar lib/library2.jar

Class-Path is a standard java parameter in the manifest file and can contain a space separated list of external libraries. When you specify a relative path it is relative to the location of the EWSTerabot.jar
The advantage of doing this is you just have to pass your jar to the java command to start your application.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `-C` option of the `jar` command which tells to switch to the specified folder and include the files and folders listed after that.

For example to include the `ews` folder/package in the jar file:

```
jar cfm EWSTerabot.jar ./MyManifest.txt -C bin/ ews/
```

Comment: Thanks! I have some external libraries (in the form of jars) I need to import. They are located at ./libs. How can I package these with the JAR?